# iOS 9 CoreSpotlight API Xamarin Crash on Index()

Tags: ios, xamarin, ios9, spotlight, corespotlight

I have the following lines of code:

```
var attributes = new CSSearchableItemAttributeSet ();
attributes.Title = "Title";
attributes.ContentDescription = "Description";
var item = new CSSearchableItem ("1", "space", attributes);

if (CSSearchableIndex.IsIndexingAvailable) {
    CSSearchableIndex.DefaultSearchableIndex.Index (new [] { item }, (error) => {
        if (error != null) {
            Console.WriteLine("success");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("fail");
        }
    }); 
}
```

which give me this kind of crash and "success" branch is never reached:

```
2015-09-18 23:24:30.136 Ross[189:3538] critical:    0   App_                                0x02f3a715 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 240
2015-09-18 23:24:30.137 Ross[189:3538] critical:    1   App_                                0x02f44437 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 150
2015-09-18 23:24:30.138 Ross[189:3538] critical:    2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x36cd485f _sigtramp + 42
2015-09-18 23:24:30.139 Ross[189:3538] critical:    3   MobileCoreServices                  0x26b9be45 <redacted> + 12
2015-09-18 23:24:30.140 Ross[189:3538] critical:    4   MobileCoreServices                  0x26b9be45 <redacted> + 12
2015-09-18 23:24:30.141 Ross[189:3538] critical:    5   MobileCoreServices                  0x26ba500d _UTTypeCopyPedigree + 60
2015-09-18 23:24:30.142 Ross[189:3538] critical:    6   CoreSpotlight                       0x2540287f <redacted> + 170
2015-09-18 23:24:30.142 Ross[189:3538] critical:    7   CoreSpotlight                       0x25416123 <redacted> + 130
2015-09-18 23:24:30.143 Ross[189:3538] critical:    8   CoreSpotlight                       0x25414f03 <redacted> + 54
2015-09-18 23:24:30.144 Ross[189:3538] critical:    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x36b40ed7 <redacted> + 10
2015-09-18 23:24:30.145 Ross[189:3538] critical:    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x36b4b04f <redacted> + 1762
2015-09-18 23:24:30.145 Ross[189:3538] critical:    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x36b4402f <redacted> + 282
2015-09-18 23:24:30.146 Ross[189:3538] critical:    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x36b4c3dd <redacted> + 400
2015-09-18 23:24:30.146 Ross[189:3538] critical:    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x36b4c24b <redacted> + 94
2015-09-18 23:24:30.147 Ross[189:3538] critical:    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36cd5e29 _pthread_wqthread + 1024
2015-09-18 23:24:30.148 Ross[189:3538] critical:    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36cd5a18 start_wqthread + 8
2015-09-18 23:24:30.149 Ross[189:3538] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
    =================================================================
```

*UPD1* Simulator gives a more detailed crash:

```
2015-09-18 23:51:05.352 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   0   App_                                0x0026b037 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 311
2015-09-18 23:51:05.353 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   1   App_                                0x00297616 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 214
2015-09-18 23:51:05.353 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0413e03b _sigtramp + 43
2015-09-18 23:51:05.353 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
2015-09-18 23:51:05.354 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   4   MobileCoreServices                  0x05651b78 _UTTypeIdentifierIsDynamic + 25
2015-09-18 23:51:05.354 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   5   MobileCoreServices                  0x0565da01 _UTTypeCopyPedigree + 91
2015-09-18 23:51:05.354 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   6   CoreSpotlight                       0x032dcbfb -[CSSearchableItem(Internal) standardizeAttributes] + 213
2015-09-18 23:51:05.355 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   7   CoreSpotlight                       0x032f73db -[CSSearchableIndex _standardizeItems:] + 167
2015-09-18 23:51:05.355 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   8   CoreSpotlight                       0x032f5928 __161-[CSSearchableIndex indexSearchableItems:deleteSearchableItemsWithIdentifiers:clientState:clientStateName:protectionClass:forBundleID:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 60
2015-09-18 23:51:05.355 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03dd8a7f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
2015-09-18 23:51:05.356 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03df66fd _dispatch_client_callout + 14
2015-09-18 23:51:05.356 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03dde3ca _dispatch_queue_drain + 1065
2015-09-18 23:51:05.356 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03dddd15 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 563
2015-09-18 23:51:05.356 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03ddf7be _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 442
2015-09-18 23:51:05.357 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03ddf5fd _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
2015-09-18 23:51:05.357 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0412a1da _pthread_wqthread + 724
2015-09-18 23:51:05.357 Ross[24134:2660436] critical:   16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04127e2e start_wqthread + 30
2015-09-18 23:51:05.358 Ross[24134:2660436] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
    =================================================================
```

Though if I change Index() line to add no items at all, there will be no crash and execution flow will hit the "fail" console case:

```
 CSSearchableIndex.DefaultSearchableIndex.Index (new CSSearchableItem[] { }, (error) => {
```

I also tried setting different properties on a `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` object, no luck.

Any ideas how to flight it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong initializer is used. Instead of calling plain

```
var attributes = new CSSearchableItemAttributeSet ();
```

I had to specify itemContentType

```
var attributes = new CSSearchableItemAttributeSet (itemContentType: "");
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CSSearchableItemAttributeSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CSSearchableItemAttributeSet/initWithItemContentType: